# How to cancel previous express request, so that new request gets executed?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, express

I have this endpoint. This api takes long time to get the response.

```
app.get('/api/execute_script',(req,res) =>{
//code here
}
```

I have following endpoint which will kill the process

```
app.get('/api/kill-process',(req,res) => {
//code here
}
```

but unless first api gets response second api doesnt get executed. How to cancel previous api request and execute the second request?

Comment: Can you explain what you're doing? Because it doesn't matter how long it takes to finish `/api/execute_script` you can always call the other endpoint without being blocked by the first one.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande im executing a script.. basically i just want to kill that process using one more api ..

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `EventEmitter` to kill the other process, all you'll need is a session/user/process identifier.

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const emitter = new EventEmitter();

app.get('/api/execute_script', async(req,res,next) => {

  const eventName = `kill-${req.user.id}`; // User/session identifier
  const proc = someProcess(); 
  const listener = () => {
     // or whatever you have to kill/destroy/abort the process
    proc.abort()
  }

  try {
    emitter.once(eventName, listener);

    await proc

    // only respond if the process was not aborted
    res.send('process done')
  } catch(e) {
    // Process should reject if aborted
    if(e.code !== 'aborted') {
      // Or whatever status code
      return res.status(504).send('Timeout');
    }
    // process error
    next(e);
  } finally {
    // cleanup
    emitter.removeListener(eventName, listener)
  }
})

app.get('/api/kill-process',(req,res) => {
  //code here
  const eventName = `kill-${req.user.id}`;
  // .emit returns true if the emitter has listener attached
  const killed = emitter.emit(eventName);

  res.send({ killed })
})
```